Sufficient and necessary condition for $(z^3)^\frac{1}{3}=z$
My goal is to give a sufficient and necessary condition for $(z^3)^\frac{1}{3}=z$  for the principal branch of the cube root.
Let $z=re^{i\theta}; \, 
-\pi \leq \theta < \pi; \, 
z^3=r^3e^{i(3\theta)}$. Now, we have that
$$
(z^3)^{\frac{1}{3}} = z 
\iff -\pi \leq 3\theta < \pi 
\iff 
-\frac{\pi}{3} \leq \theta< \frac{\pi}{3}
$$
And more generally,
$$
(z^n)^{1/n} = z 
\iff 
-\pi \leq n\operatorname{Arg}(z) < \pi 
\iff 
-\frac{\pi}{n} \leq \operatorname{Arg}(z) < \frac{\pi}{n}
$$
where $\operatorname{Arg}(z)$ is the principal argument of $z$.
Is this approach correct?

Personally, I would probably let the principal cube root of $-1$ be $e^{i\pi/3}$. This means that $((re^{i\theta})^3)^{1/3} = re^{i\theta}$ when $\theta=\frac\pi3$ but not when $\theta=-\frac\pi3$, contrary to what the question says. But you can do it this way too. How you make the branch cut and how you assign points along the cut is somewhat arbitrary.

Yes.
And note that you can picture this in an alternative way. Choosing the standard branch cut at argument $\pi$ and thinking in terms of arcs, the inequalities $-\pi \leq n \operatorname{Arg} z < \pi$ define an interval which we picture wrapped around the circle.
Consider this interval $[-\pi, \pi) = [0 - \pi, 0 + \pi)$, centered at argument $\theta_0 = 0$. For these $n$th roots, we just scale the argument down by a factor of $n$, keeping the center the same. So, we get the infinite sector consisting of those complex numbers whose arguments lie within $\tfrac{\pi}{n}$ of $0$, i.e., $[0 - \tfrac{\pi}{n}, 0 + \tfrac{\pi}{n})$.
This perspective generalizes nicely. If the branch cut occurs at $\theta_0 + \pi$ (so opposite the direction $\theta_0$), then we're continuously parametrizing complex numbers for arguments $[\theta_0 - \pi, \theta_0 + \pi)$. So for the smaller sector of arguments on the interval $[\theta_0 - \tfrac{\pi}{n}, \theta_0 + \tfrac{\pi}{n})$, the equation $(z^n)^{1/n} = z$ is satisfied.
